# How To Disable Hazelcast Rest Api On Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to disable hazelcast rest api on spring boot app. 
I use curl to send data for example;

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "bar" http://192....:5705/hazelcast/rest/maps/mapName/Example
```

return is accept. I dont want to accept so I need to disable hazelcast rest api.
 I tried;

```
  Config hazelConfig = new Config();
  hazelConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled","false");
```

and

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled", String.valueOf(false))
```

but not working.

applicationContext-hazelcast.xml :

```
<beans...
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcastInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="..." password="...."/>
        <hz:network port="5705" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"
                              multicast-group="..."
                              multicast-port="..."/>
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members></hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="rights"
                backup-count="2"
                max-size="0"
                eviction-percentage="30"
                read-backup-data="true"
                eviction-policy="NONE"
                merge-policy="com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy"/>
        <hz:map name="users"
                backup-count="2"
                max-size="0"
                eviction-percentage="30"
                read-backup-data="true"
                eviction-policy="NONE"
                merge-policy="com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy"/>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
 </beans>
```

and hazelcast properties;

```
    @Bean(name = "hazelcastInstance")
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {

    Config hazelConfig = new Config();

    // group config
    hazelConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(...);
    hazelConfig.getGroupConfig().setPassword(...);

  //rest config again
    hazelConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled","false");

    hazelConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.health.monitoring.level", "OFF");

    //rest config again
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled", String.valueOf(false));

    // management center config
        hazelConfig.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true)
                .setUrl(...)
                .setUpdateInterval(...);// in seconds


    //network config
    hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPort(...);
    hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);

        hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setMulticastGroup(...);
        hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setMulticastPort(...);

    hazelConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(...);


    // Defining maps to be used in cache
    MapConfig mapConfigRights = new MapConfig();
    mapConfigRights.setName(..);
    mapConfigRights.setInMemoryFormat(...);
    //Near cache is highly recommended for the maps that are read-mostly
    mapConfigRights.setNearCacheConfig(...);
    mapConfigRights.setReadBackupData(true);
    mapConfigRights.setEvictionPolicy(...);
    mapConfigRights.setMergePolicy(...);
    hazelConfig.getMapConfigs().put(..., mapConfigRights);

    return HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(hazelConfig);
}
```

I use hazelcast versions from 3.5.3 to 3.8.4 but still accepts rest api.

Thank you.

Comment: you are setting this property in hazelcast server,correct ?

Comment: Yes I believe. I added applicationContext-hazelcast.xml to question. I think its fine.

Comment: Hazelcast REST client is disabled by default, you need to set `hazelcast.rest.enabled` system property to `true` to use it. Can you please check whether you are not enabling it at any point of your application configuration?

Comment: Yes but there is a problem which is not disable. I want to disable it not enable.